# Hanoi Towers non-recursive wrong steps

Tags: c, non-recursive

I have to write a program that will solve the hanoi towers.
I have 3 columns, A-B-C and all the discs will have to be on the B column as the result. I have to write out the steps that each disc performs and in what order. 
I tried to write it on my own, it works to some extent.
Some problems are:

1. The numbers are not written out correctly, at the n-j it should
   calculate the n-j but it's always 1, but it shouldn't be.
2. The steps that the program performs are good only to some extent,
   for example the last 3 or 4 steps are always wrong.

What did I write incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int n,i,j,k,first_pos,last_pos,num_ofsteps,num;
    char first_peg,next_peg;

    printf("Enter the number of disks: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;++i) {
        a[i]=0;
    }

    num_ofsteps = pow(2,n);
    first_pos = 0;
    last_pos = n-1;

    for (i=0;i<num_ofsteps-1;++i) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            if (a[n-1]==0) {
                a[n-1] = 1;
                printf("1 steps: A->B\n");
            } else if (a[n-1]==1) {
                a[n-1] = 2;
                printf("1 steps: B->C\n");
            } else if (a[n-1]==2) {
                a[n-1] = 0;
                printf("1 steps: C->A\n");
            }
        } else {
            for (j=n-1;j>=0;--j) {
                if (a[j]!=a[j-1]) {

                    if ((a[j]==0 && a[j-1]==1) || (a[j]==1 && a[j-1]==0)) {
                        next_peg = 'C';
                    } else if ((a[j]==1 && a[j-1]==2) || (a[j]==2 && a[j-1]==1)) {
                        next_peg = 'A';
                    } else if ((a[j]==0 && a[j-1]==2) || (a[j]==2 && a[j-1]==0)) {
                        next_peg = 'B';
                    }

                    num=n-j;
                    if (a[j-1]==0) {
                        first_peg = 'A';
                        a[j-1] = 1;
                        printf("%d steps: %c->%c\n",num,first_peg,next_peg);
                        break;
                    } else if (a[j-1]==1) {
                        first_peg = 'B';
                        a[j-1] = 2;
                        printf("%d steps: %c->%c\n",num,first_peg,next_peg);
                        break;
                    } else if (a[j-1]==2) {
                        first_peg = 'C';
                        a[j-1] = 0;
                        printf("%d steps: %c->%c\n",num,first_peg,next_peg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include code with texts in english - it would be very helpful. Also your code is quite unreadable - consider some changes (like more verbose variable names).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_6nsViVM00
This might help..

Comment: I said that I am not allowed to use recursion.

Comment: @Esse Done, changed it to english.

Comment: Does this help? http://justprogrammng.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/hello-all-this-is-my-first-post.html#.VEOVvxadiSo